# Windows 11 command prompt printing characters instead of coloured text

Tags: windows-10, python, cmd.exe, colors, windows-11

When I run my Python program from the `Visual Studio Code` integrated terminal everything goes fine, and I have my colors as they are supposed to be, like in this screenshot:

[image: VS Code terminal with color]

---

But if I run **exactly the same file** from **the same folder** but directly from `cmd.exe`, this is what happens:

[image: Console with unexpected errors]

---

To make my output coloured I used the module [`colorama`](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/) (`v0.4.4`), but it only contains constants (which are the characters which in the second screenshot are displayed like `[36m`) and since it works perfectly in VS Code I don't think the problem is caused by the module.

Has anybody had the same problem? In this case could you tell me how did you solve it? Does it have something to do with the system settings?

---

## EDIT

As suggested in the answer, I tried to do it with `Windows Terminal`, something that I had not tried because the at-time called `Powershell` didn't work, so after upgrading to `Windows 11` (actually at the time of the screenshot above I was already using `11`) I didn't try to use this terminal.

And guess what? It works perfectly, thank you!

[image: Windows Terminal]

Comment: note that powershell has nothing to do with terminals (like conhost, xterm, VS terminal, Windows terminal...) because it's a shell like cmd, bash or ksh... If the terminal supports ANSI sequence then formatting with ANSI sequence works regardless of the shell

Comment: So from a different terminal I can access a shell like powershell or cmd? I'll read something about it, thanks :)

Comment: no, it's the reverse. You can run different shells in a terminal. A terminal is simply an input/output device, like the mechanical terminals in the past

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those `]` things are part of the [ANSI sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) for formatting. The terminal in VS Code supports ANSI sequences so obviously you'll see color properly. The one you're seeing on the screenshot is conhost.exe which is the classic terminal that cmd.exe attaches to, and you have disabled ANSI sequence support in it somehow. Either the script calls Win32 console APIs directly and disable ANSI sequence support (unlikely), or the feature was turned off by some other method

I believe it's because you're on Windows 10 and the [windows-11](/questions/tagged/windows-11) tag on the question is wrong. The screenshot looks completely same to Windows 10. Besides on Windows 11 you don't need to do anything to enable ANSI sequence support in conhost.exe, whereas on Windows 10 you may need to create a registry key to enable it

So the first solution is to create a new DWORD named `VirtualTerminalLevel` in registry at the path `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console` with value 1. After that conhost.exe will display color correctly

The better solution is to use [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/Microsoft/Terminal) which is the newer terminal for Windows and has more features beside ANSI sequence support such as emojis, full Unicode support...

See also

- [Can we use more colors in batch script?](https://superuser.com/a/1416935/241386)
- [Console Virtual Terminal Sequences](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences)